# Arrow function returning component with TypeScript in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to build an app in React Native using Typescript, but i'm facing some problems with some of the typescript rules.
I just copy and paste an UI Kitten component code and it returns a TypeError

`const PersonIcon = (props: any) => ( <Icon {...props} /> );`

`const BellIcon = (props: any) => ( <Icon {...props} name='bell-outline'/> );`

`const EmailIcon = (props: any) => ( <Icon {...props} name='email-outline'/> );`

And then using it in the component:

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

return(
    <TabBar
        selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
        onSelect={index => setSelectedIndex(index)}>
        <Tab icon={EmailIcon} title='USERS'/>
        <Tab icon={BellIcon} title='ORDERS'/>
        <Tab icon={EmailIcon} title='TRANSACTIONS'/>
    </TabBar>
)
```

And with that I can't procceed because I can't find something like a tutorial which teaches how to use TypeScript in React Native. Could someone help me? I know this is a newbie error, but I really can't find the solution

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d22PB.png)

Comment: What component is `<Tab` and `<TabBar`?

Comment: Why you decide that error related to incorrect using of typescript? In the error says: it can't read property of undefined, look at Home.jsx file. It's runtime error, typescript compilation occurs at build time.